# MATLAB:labelling axis with imshow

Tags: matlab, label, imshow

I'm trying to use imshow command to show an image. What I could not come up with is to label image axis according to my x and y values. My code is below:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(0:0.01:1,0:0.01:1);
u     = 5;
v     = 1;
z     = sin(2*pi*(u*X+v*Y));
imshow(z);
axis on
```

When I use "axis on", it shows 0 to 100. But I want is 0 to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify x- and y-axis values in `imshow` as follows:

```
imshow(z, 'XData', 0:.01:1, 'YData', 0:.01:1)
```

(and then you of course need `axis on` as in your code).